# Remove HTML tags from string (R Programming)

Tags: html, r, tags

Is there an easy way to remove HTML tags from a character string in R?

Currently I'm extracting out survey data from an XML document and for the title of the question have HTML from the survey design in it, like this.

```
"Why did you give this performance question a low score?<br />"
```

Any way to easily remove the `<br />`?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate (more recent Q&A): [*Removing html tags from a string in R*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227294/removing-html-tags-from-a-string-in-r)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `?gsub` and `?regex`.  Here's some simple code to remove the `<br />`, but it won't work for all potential HTML tags.

```
> string <- "Why did you give this performance question a low score?<br />"
> gsub("<.*/>","",string)
[1] "Why did you give this performance question a low score?"
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it got me on my way to finding 'gsub("<(.|\n)*?>","",string)'

Comment: Just to flag it may be worth consulting this sage advice on the subject of regex for parsing html.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1156245