# Removing html tags from a string in R

Tags: string, r

I'm trying to read web page source into R and process it as strings. I'm trying to take the paragraphs out and remove the html tags from the paragraph text. I'm running into the following problem:

I tried implementing a function to remove the html tags:

```
cleanFun=function(fullStr)
{
 #find location of tags and citations
 tagLoc=cbind(str_locate_all(fullStr,"<")[[1]][,2],str_locate_all(fullStr,">")[[1]][,1]);

 #create storage for tag strings
 tagStrings=list()

 #extract and store tag strings
 for(i in 1:dim(tagLoc)[1])
 {
   tagStrings[i]=substr(fullStr,tagLoc[i,1],tagLoc[i,2]);
 }

 #remove tag strings from paragraph
 newStr=fullStr
 for(i in 1:length(tagStrings))
 {
   newStr=str_replace_all(newStr,tagStrings[[i]][1],"")
 }
 return(newStr)
};
```

This works for some tags but not all tags, an example where this fails is following string:

```
test="junk junk<a href=\"/wiki/abstraction_(mathematics)\" title=\"abstraction (mathematics)\"> junk junk"
```

The goal would be to obtain:

```
cleanFun(test)="junk junk junk junk"
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. I thought it might be something to do with string length or escape characters, but I couldn't find a solution involving those.

Comment: Edited to fix some mistakes made when entering the code.

Comment: There's a lot going on here... To start, this is R, so no `;`. You're basically looking for `gsub` and an appropriate regular expression (in this case, already answered here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225690/removing-data-with-tags-from-a-vector/10225883#10225883). There are other problems with the code (`dim(tagLoc)[1]` is not doing what you think it is), but I don't think that's the point of your question

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This can be achieved simply through regular expressions and the grep family:

```
cleanFun <- function(htmlString) {
  return(gsub("<.*?>", "", htmlString))
}
```

This will also work with multiple html tags in the same string!

This finds any instances of the pattern `<.*?>` in the htmlString and replaces it with the empty string "".  The ? in `.*?` makes it non greedy, so if you have multiple tags (e.g., `<a> junk </a>`) it will match `<a>` and `</a>` instead of the whole string.

Comment: Basically what it does, is it finds any instances of the pattern `"<.*?>" in the `htmlString', and replaces it with the empty string `""`, and returns the result. 
For the pattern matching you should go learn regular expressions. The only slightly tricky part is the `".*?"`, the `?` makes it non greedy, so if you have multiple tags, e.g "<a> junk </a>" it will match "<a>" and "</a>" instead of the whole string.

Comment: "_Every time you attempt to parse HTML with regular expressions, the unholy child weeps the blood of virgins, and Russian hackers pwn your webapp_" From [this seminal answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1156245).

Comment: Fine I'll bite – removal != parsing

Answer (score 33):

You can also do this with two functions in the [rvest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/index.html) package:

```
library(rvest)

strip_html <- function(s) {
    html_text(read_html(s))
}
```

Example output:

```
> strip_html("junk junk<a href=\"/wiki/abstraction_(mathematics)\" title=\"abstraction (mathematics)\"> junk junk")
[1] "junk junk junk junk"
```

[Note that you should not use regexes to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/712603).

Comment: Note that the input string MUST contain some html tags, or read_html will treat the argument as a local file path

Comment: `html_text(read_html(charToRaw(s)))` should solve this problem.

Comment: I cannot emphasize @Motin's comments and patr1ckm's answer enough. Such a strange error.

Comment: Note that `read_html(charToRaw(''))` will also fail.

Comment: Also note that `html_text2()` will be preferable to `html_text()` in most cases.

Comment: Since `read_html(charToRaw(''))` fails, if you accept trimming spaces, this is an option:
`read_html(charToRaw(paste0(' ', your_string)), trim=T)`

Answer (score 10):

Another approach, using `tm.plugin.webmining`, which uses `XML` internally.

```
> library(tm.plugin.webmining)
> extractHTMLStrip("junk junk<a href=\"/wiki/abstraction_(mathematics)\" title=\"abstraction (mathematics)\"> junk junk")
[1] "junk junk junk junk"
```

Comment: Note: this library requires Java, which may be a limitation in various R server environments

Answer (score 7):

An approach using the qdap package:

```
library(qdap)
bracketX(test, "angle")

## > bracketX(test, "angle")
## [1] "junk junk junk junk"
```

Comment: I have installed your package and had a look at the source code for the various functions. `bracketX` is very useful for a much more general class of problems. Another one for the toolbox.

Answer (score 4):

It is best not to parse html using regular expressions. [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Use a package like `XML`. Source the html code in parse it using for example `htmlParse` and use xpaths to find the quantities relevant to you.

UPDATE:

To answer the OP's question

```
require(XML)
xData <- htmlParse('yourfile.html')
xpathSApply(xData, 'appropriate xpath', xmlValue)
```

Comment: Does that apply in this case though? He doesn't want to parse the tags at all, he wants to strip them out.

Comment: The OP probably just wants to use `xpathSapply(doc, 'somepath', xmlValue)`.

Comment: The link you've given is provided so often when ever someone suggests regex for HTML, but it really is just a guideline not a rule.  I'd agree that XML (etc.) should be used if possible, but sometimes it's not possible or impractical.  To merely think `HTML +  regex = bad` is avoiding decision making.  Sometimes regex is appropriate.  We don't know the data format or source.  This was up voted 2 times but doesn't actually give the OP an answer.

Comment: The OP has given little detail about what they ultimately want. They have provided a brief sketch which takes the appearance of regex being used as a parser. It would be wrong not to inform the OP that this is very often if not always a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

It may be easier with sub or gsub ?

```
> test  <- "junk junk<a href=\"/wiki/abstraction_(mathematics)\" title=\"abstraction (mathematics)\"> junk junk"
> gsub(pattern = "<.*>", replacement = "", x = test)
[1] "junk junk junk junk"
```

Comment: 1 problem with this code could be, it replaces from the first appearance of `<` to the last appearance of `>`. so when there are multiple html tags, then this could be a problem

Answer (score 1):

First, your subject line is misleading; there are no backslashes in the string you posted. You've fallen victim to one of the classic blunders: not as bad as getting involved in a land war in Asia, but notable all the same. You're mistaking R's use of `\` to denote escaped characters for literal backslashes. In this case, `\"` means the double quote mark, not the two literal characters `\` and `"`. You can use `cat` to see what the string would actually look like if escaped characters were treated literally.

Second, you're using regular expressions to parse HTML. (They don't appear in your code, but they are used under the hood in `str_locate_all` and `str_replace_all`.) This is another of the classic blunders; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) for more exposition.

Third, you should have mentioned in your post that you're using the `stringr` package, but this is only a minor blunder by comparison.