# Extract Exact Word in R

Tags: r, html-parsing, extract

I want to extract some exact words from a variable (in fact, url's) and create a new variable which contains only the extracted words. Examining the patterns I found that I want the words the characters \\"> and ", as follow:

```
> dados$source[1:20]
 [1] "<a href=\\\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\\\" rel=\\\"nofollow\\\">Twitter for iPhone</a>"  

 [2] "<a href=\\\"http://twitter.com/download/android\\\" rel=\\\"nofollow\\\">Twitter for Android</a>"

 [3] "<a href=\\\"http://twitter.com\\\" rel=\\\"nofollow\\\">Twitter Web Client</a>"
```

How can I do it?

Comment: If `links` is the data above, something like `library(purrr); library(rvest); links %>% map(read_html) %>% map_chr(html_text)` depending on what you're trying to grab, which is unclear.

Comment: `dput(dados$source[1:20])`

Comment: @alistaire Sorry, I want to grab the devices, i.e., iPhone, Android, Web Client, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got HTML, use an HTML parser like rvest to parse to strings. Once you've got non-HTML strings, you can use regex.

```
library(purrr)    # use lapply and sapply if you prefer
library(rvest)

# representative data
links <- c("<a href=\\\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\\\" rel=\\\"nofollow\\\">Twitter for iPhone</a>", 
    "<a href=\\\"http://twitter.com/download/android\\\" rel=\\\"nofollow\\\">Twitter for Android</a>", 
    "<a href=\\\"http://twitter.com\\\" rel=\\\"nofollow\\\">Twitter Web Client</a>")

links %>% map(read_html) %>% 
    map_chr(html_text) %>% 
    sub('Twitter (for )?', '', .)

## [1] "iPhone"     "Android"    "Web Client"
```

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure I understand exactly what patterns you want to extract. However, using Regex would be the way to go.
An example from the question: [Removing html tags from a string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227294/removing-html-tags-from-a-string-in-r)

```
cleanFun <- function(htmlString) {
  return(gsub("<.*?>", "", htmlString))
}
```