# Download shiny HTML output as txt or pdf

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am trying to download HTML output from a shiny app as either txt or pdf. I have managed to download it as txt file but it comes with the html code for breaks which I wish to get rid of. Download works when the app is opened on the browser. Any help will be appreciated. My code is as below.

```
 library(shiny)

 server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$textview <- renderUI({
         movie <- "Crazy Rich Asians"
         summary <- "Rachel Chu is happy to accompany her longtime 
                     boyfriend, Nick, to his best friend's wedding in Singapore. She's 
                   also surprised to learn that Nick's family is extremely 
                   wealthy and he's considered one of the country's most 
                    eligible bachelors. "
          director <- "Jon M. Chu"
         text <- data.frame(movie,summary,director)
       brief=""
       details <- text
       if (dim(details)[1]<5){
            for(i in seq(from=1,to=dim(details)[1])){
                  brief <-paste(brief,
                  paste("Movie: ",details[i,"movie"]),
                  sep="<br/><br/>")
                  brief <-paste(brief,
                  paste("Director: ",details[i,"director"]),
                  sep="<br/><br/>")
                  brief <-paste(brief,
                  paste("Summary: ",details[i,"summary"]),
                 sep="<br/><br/>")
     }

       save01 <<- brief
  }
 HTML(brief) 

 })


output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

  filename = function() {
    file <- "saveddetails.txt"
    file
   },

  content = function(file) {
    write(save01, file)
   }
  )


})


 ui_panel <- 
      tabPanel("Multi-Select Input Test",
         sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
              downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'),
             br()
           ),
           mainPanel(
             tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Text",htmlOutput("textview"))

             )
            )
          ))


 ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage(" ",ui_panel))

  runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```

Any suggestion or insight on how to download the html output as txt or pdf file will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any suggestion or insight on how to download the html output as txt or pdf file will be highly appreciated.

Using the [rvest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/index.html) package, this function will return text without html tags. This code can be placed in your shiny app outside the server and ui functions.

```
library(rvest)

strip_html <- function(s) {
    html_text(read_html(s))
}
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34344957/10297551

You can then insert `strip_html` into your `downloadHandler` code in the Shiny server function.

```
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

    filename = function() {
      file <- "saveddetails.txt"
      file
    },

    content = function(file) {
      write(strip_html(save01), file)
    },
      contentType = "text"
  )
```

Comment: Hello Dean Thank you for the response. The solution removes the html breaks but the text is now without spaces for example **Movie: Crazy Rich AsiansDirector:  Jon M. ChuSummary: .....**