# Function in a dplyr pipeline executes the first item repeatedly rather than one for each

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table full of data, where one of the columns is scraped from a webpage and thus is full of HTML tags I don't need.  I was looking to remove the HTML tags.  I found this thread: [Removing html tags from a string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227294/removing-html-tags-from-a-string-in-r)

I eventually got the regex version working (so my actual problem is solved), but originally tried implementing David Robinson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34344957/27290) which utilised the `rvest` package.  However, when I tried that, I had an issue where instead of running the function across each table row's string, it just performed it on the first row and copied the result down.  I'm curious as to what I was doing wrong, so I know how to fix my calls next time I hit this kind of issue.  Here's an example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(rvest)

mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column("Car") %>%
  select(Car) %>%
  mutate(html_string = paste0("<a>",Car,"</a>")) %>%
  mutate(cleaned_string = html_text(read_html(html_string)))
```

[image]

Comment: My guess is that `read_html` is not vectorised, and only takes a single string (character vector of length 1) rather than a vector of many strings. So you're only getting one string returned and repeated for every row.

Comment: Which is fine, but I'm surprised this code doesn't throw a warning. I'd file a bug report if this hasn't already been addressed.

Answer (score 1):

@thelatemail is correct I believe, `read_html` works only for single url, for it to work for multiple url's you need to either use `rowwise` or use some kind of looping.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column("Car") %>%
  select(Car) %>%
  mutate(html_string = paste0("<a>",Car,"</a>")) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(cleaned_string = html_text(read_html(html_string)))


#  Car               html_string              cleaned_string   
#   <chr>             <chr>                    <chr>            
# 1 Mazda RX4         <a>Mazda RX4</a>         Mazda RX4        
# 2 Mazda RX4 Wag     <a>Mazda RX4 Wag</a>     Mazda RX4 Wag    
# 3 Datsun 710        <a>Datsun 710</a>        Datsun 710       
# 4 Hornet 4 Drive    <a>Hornet 4 Drive</a>    Hornet 4 Drive   
# 5 Hornet Sportabout <a>Hornet Sportabout</a> Hornet Sportabout
# 6 Valiant           <a>Valiant</a>           Valiant          
# 7 Duster 360        <a>Duster 360</a>        Duster 360       
# 8 Merc 240D         <a>Merc 240D</a>         Merc 240D        
# 9 Merc 230          <a>Merc 230</a>          Merc 230         
#10 Merc 280          <a>Merc 280</a>          Merc 280         
# … with 22 more rows
```

Or using `purrr::map_chr`

```
mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column("Car") %>%
  select(Car) %>%
  mutate(html_string = paste0("<a>",Car,"</a>")) %>%
  mutate(cleaned_string = purrr::map_chr(html_string, ~html_text(read_html(.))))
```